# Does 几棵参天大树字 refer to trees (树) or characters (字)?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This is from a grade-5 composition:

> 左边，有**几棵参天大树字**、直直的挺立在那里。
> <sub>[快乐的秋游](http://zuowen.xuexiaodaquan.com/e/2017/0510/1021905.html)</sub>

I'm confused as to whether 几棵参天大树字 refers to trees (树), or characters (字).  The measure word 棵 suggests it's referring to trees, but the 字 at the end makes it sound like it's referring to gigantic characters (like you would have at an amusement park).

**Question**: Does 几棵参天大树字 refer to trees (树) or characters (字)?

Comment: 字 should be deleted. It's a typo I guess.

Comment: This is a sick sentence. There is no such expression in Chinese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree 字 is a typo that should not be there.

> 左边，有几棵参天大树、直直的挺立在那里。

左边，有几行参天大树般高的字、直直的挺立在那里。(On the left, there are several columns of characters as tall as a towering tree, standing there straight. ) would be correct if the object was the characters and not the tree

Comment: Also, 逗号（，） may be a better fit than 顿号（、）.